# Translation of integration contour

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

I have an argument where, with a meromorphic function $\phi$ satisfying $\phi(s) = \phi(1-s)$, the following equality appears:
$$\int_{(2)} \phi(s) y^{-s} \, ds = \int_{(1/2)} \phi(s) y^{-s} \, ds$$

where the integration domains are the vertical lines of real part fixed to $2$ and $1/2$ respectively. For me a change of variables would give a relation between integrals on $(2)$ and $(-1)$, because these are symmetric with respect to $s \mapsto 1-s$, however I do not understand why the equality above is true.

Is there any standard trick I should see to prove it?

Comment: Sometimes that's written as $\displaystyle \int_{2\,-\,i\infty}^{2\,+\,i\infty} \varphi(s) y^{-s} \, ds. \qquad$

Comment: There should be further terms for residues of poles between the two vertical lines, in general. Also, for the argument to be completely legitimate, the top and bottom of the rectangles approximating the infinite strip must go to $0$...